# select radio button with custom label

Tags: vue.js, radio-button

I have an array of colors. I want to use them to choose colors for the text. I use the radio button because I only want to select one. I custom the default radio by using a label. The problem I'm having is that the radio only selects one but my label can select multiple. How can I fix it? It's hard to understand so this is a picture about my problem

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center flex-wrap mb-7">
        <span class="w--26 flex-fixed pe-3 mb-5">{{
          $t('setting.setting_theme.title_background')
        }}</span>
        <div v-for="color in list_colors" :key="color.id" class="me-5 mb-5">
          <input
            :v-model="color.checked"
            type="radio"
            class=""
            :id="color.id"
            name="selectTitleBackground"
            @click="color.checked = !color.checked"
          />
          <label
            class="w--8 h--8 flex-center cursor-pointer border"
            :for="color.id"
            :style="{ backgroundColor: color.value }"
            ><i
              v-if="color.checked"
              :class="{ 'text-dark': color.value == '#fff' }"
              class="fal fa-check text-light"
            ></i
          ></label>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcnY2.png)

Answer (score 1):

The model that is used on the inputs is `color.checked`. This `color` object is coming from `v-for="color in list_colors"`. So checking the input is changing each individual color object. You need to use a data property to store the checked color:

```
data() {
    return {
        selectedColorId: 1
    }
}


<input
   :v-model="selectedColorId"
   type="radio"
   :id="color.id"
   :value="color.id"
   name="selectTitleBackground"
/>
```

You also dont need the click event on the input as this should be handled by the input binding. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Radio

And the adding of the tick icon:

```
<i v-if="color.id === selectedColorId"
    :class="{ 'text-dark': color.value == '#fff' }"
    class="fal fa-check text-light"
></i>
```

Comment: But how Can I show the check icon based on the radio button? What do I need to pass to the check icon? could you give me an example?

Comment: I've added an example

Comment: Okay, I understand your answer. But it's not the answer I need. With your answer, the check icon will show when the id equal to the selectedColorId, and in this case, it'll be 1. But when I check another radio, the check icon is still there. I think that I need to bind the selectedColorIddy dynamically but I can't figure it out

Comment: Here's a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/4Lnokecu/

Comment: Oh, I got it. I just need v-model and :value like you said. I don't need to use :v-model and name property. By the way thanks you so much